# Quick clicking on the badge tracker icon opens the modal pop up twice

Tags: bug, badge-progress

I clicked twice within a second on the gear icon for tracking badges on the profile activity page.

This resulted two `Select your badge` modal pop ups.

This can be verified by clicking on the close button instead of changing the badge. After the closing the top modal, we'll be presented with modal hidden below it.

**Browser:** Tested this on Chrome.

Additionally this can be verified by looking at the HTML in inspect mode. See the boxed area.

[image]

Comment: Confirmed on Safari 9 too. And it's not just twice: the number of new `<div>`s that appear is as high as the number of times you can click before it appears. My "highscore" is 7.